# clGetProgramBuildInfo returns CL_BUILD_NONE though the program gives correct output

Tags: parallel-processing, gpu, opencl, gpgpu

I was testing a simple vector add program from Nvidia's opencl code examples. It gives the correct vector addition results. Just to experiment, I was trying to see the program build status and build log by adding the following lines after clBuildProgram is called:

```
size_t size = 0;
ret=clGetProgramBuildInfo(program,device_id, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_STATUS ,0,NULL,&size);

cl_build_status *status=(cl_build_status *)malloc(sizeof(cl_build_status));
clGetProgramBuildInfo(program,device_id, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_STATUS ,size,status,NULL);
printf("\nBuild status=%d\n",*status); 

ret = clGetProgramBuildInfo(program,device_id, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG ,0,NULL,&size);
char *buildlog=(char*)malloc(size);
buildlog[size] = '\n';
ret = clGetProgramBuildInfo(program,device_id, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG ,size,buildlog,NULL);
printf("\n\nBuildlog:   %s\n\n",buildlog);
```

The status returns "0" which means CL_BUILD_NONE and the buildlog doen't print anything(probably returns an empty string)

According to the opencl documentation, CL_BUILD_NONE is returned when no build has been performed on the specified program object for device.

Comment: What was the output of `clBuildProgram`?

Comment: returns CL_SUCCESS. The code works perfectly fine

Comment: I just found some information that the [compiler caches the build output](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/disable-caching-by-the-opencl-compiler/23752/4), and you can disable this by setting the environment variable `CUDA_CACHE_DISABLE` to `1`. This might be needed to receive the build log on every run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `cl.h` header:

```
/* cl_build_status */
#define CL_BUILD_SUCCESS                            0
#define CL_BUILD_NONE                               -1
#define CL_BUILD_ERROR                              -2
#define CL_BUILD_IN_PROGRESS                        -3
```

So, you got right info.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. But then why am I getting an empty string when I try to print the "buildlog"?

Comment: @saint_shark - the build log used to contain build errors, so no errors => the log is empty. However it isn't stated clearly in the standard, it looks like a common practice.